# Obtain elevation from a request lat,long with a map .tif

Tags: r, elevation, api, maps

I am trying to get the elevation between two points in a route of Spain using APIs with HTTP request. I am using OpenStreetMap to get the routes, but I don't know how extract elevation with other tool.
I found out that SMRT has elevations from NASA and I have a .tif with the map, but I don't know:

- how can I obtain the elevation from a .tif with a lat,long request in R?

Now I have this:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

r<-raster("30n030w_20101117_gmted_bln075.tif")

test.dat <- structure(list(latitude = c(43.421604,43.42076,43.423283,43.422585,43.422546,43.21036), longitude = c(-5.825145,-5.8239202,-5.8272586,-5.8240676,-5.8240047,-5.822057)), .Names = c("latitude", 
                                                                                                                                                 "longitude"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
points <- cbind(test.dat$longitude,test.dat$latitude)
pts2=SpatialPoints(points,proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
pts3=spTransform(pts2,projection(r))
coordinates(pts3)
extract(r,pts3)
```

With this code I obtain this values:

```
164 161 158 161 161 511
```

Are them the elevation in meters?

Comment: please show us that you have made some attempt to answer this question on your own before asking.

Comment: I've added more details